# iOS: Converting my project into library

Tags: ios, svn, shared-libraries

I have developed a project integrated with SVN, is intended to be plug-and-play to many other projects such that when I modify this project, other projects should able to just update it rather than every time overwriting manually. My problem is all components(files) of this project referes to shared app delegate where I have all server communications method written. App Delegate communicates with the server, set the required data, and notify the changes.

If I want to integrate this project with another project then that project has to have delegate name AppDelegate and needs to copy all server communication methods. If I don't use delegate name as AppDelegate then I have to modify all other component where I refer shared delegate.

Could someone please tell me what could be the best practices for converting my project into library so that it won't required anything manually changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you write server communications in Appdelegate? Better you could have created a Communication manager class, where all the web service call goes. And use your classes (not generated by Apple) to create static library. Refer this link for steps to create static library http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/

Comment: I could do this but problem with static library is, if code contains project wide settings and different images, how would you handle it?